# Why does iTunes use 100% cpu when syncing photos?

Tags: macos, itunes

Is it resizing them or something? It's using ~98% of my CPU while I'm syncing some pictures to an iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a small thumbnail copy, and then a larger (but usually still tiny compared to original camera resolution) picture that is 'optimized' for ipad/iphone/etc.